# How to render a VUE3 component based on Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to have an autocomplete: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-simple-typeahead the problem is, input datas cant be fixed, they come from an ajax request. But after page loaded, I cant seem to be able to modify those values. I was reading about `computed`, `mount`, `store` - but im so confused.
I thought I have to render that element after the ajax request is loaded. But how to?

Comment: What exactly did you try? " thought I have to render that element after" - you need to re-render it, and this is done for you when you change reactive data, that's what reactivity is about

Comment: Your request is too general. We have no way of knowing what you know and what you don't, therefore what you're confused about. Consider showing us what you tried so far and, most likely, someone will be able to tell what you're missing or at least point you in the right direction or to some useful example. I'd argue there are plenty of examples of how to fetch data in a Vue app and/or manage the results but, then again, without knowing much about what you actually need, it would be impossible to point you to an example which you might find useful.

Answer (score 1):

> But after page loaded, I cant seem to be able to modify those values

This seems to be going against the basic idea of Vue. I am not saying all 3rd party components are able to handle all the changes to all their properties, but usually they should.

In this particular case, you just need to update the items property once your ajax request completes. In order to do that, define the items as part of the data in the parent component where you will be managing your ajax request, and change the items once ajax request returns.

If that does not work, it is probably a limitation of the vue3-simple-typeahead component (again, I will be very surprised). But in case the component is indeed built this way - basically the items must be given upfront - you can destroy and recreate the vue3-simple-typeahead instance when your ajax returns. This is doable by binding the **key** property to a state variable, e.g. a counter. And when your ajax finishes, increase the counter. It will force the component to unmount and mount again because its key has changed.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is load the data when the component is load:

```
<template>
  <Dropdown :items="data" />
</template>
<script>
import { defineComponent, onMounted, ref } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const data = ref()

    async function loadYourData() {
       //load data
       data.value = your-data-get-from-api
    }

    onMounted(async () => {
      await loadYourData()
    }

    return {
      data,
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

[See lifecycle hooks for more details](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html)